# Program in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with writing my program in Python **2.7**.
My problem is that I am not sure how to start the program again if the user inputs 'yes'. Here is my program:

```
import random

#Set up the lists for charades and the  answers (words)
charadelist = ["Mary's father has 5 daughters: Chacha, Chichi, Cheche, Chocho. What is the name of the 5th daughter?"]             
wordlist = ["Mary"]

lencharades = len(charadelist)

lenwords = len(wordlist)

rndnum = random.randrange (0, lenwords)

answer = wordlist[rndnum]

charade = charadelist[rndnum]

print "***Welcome to Charades!***"
print "You are given a charade. Try to guess the answer:"


print '"'+charade+'"'
guess = raw_input('Your answer: ')

if guess == answer:
    print "Well done!"
else:
    print "Sorry, the correct answer is " + '"'+answer+'"' + '.'

print 'Do you want to play again?'
reply = raw_input('Type `yes` or `no`: ')
if reply == 'yes':

# How do I run the program again??? Please help

if reply == 'no':
    print 'Thanks for playing!'
    exit
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. You are looking for loops. This question as it is, is not helpful for anyone. Go through some Python tutorials on loops and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend running your game inside a function, that way you can call it any time:

```
import random

def runGame():
    #Set up the lists for charades and the  answers (words)
    charadelist = ["Mary's father has 5 daughters: Chacha, Chichi, Cheche, Chocho. What is the name of the 5th daughter?"]             
    wordlist = ["Mary"]
    lencharades = len(charadelist)
    lenwords = len(wordlist)
    rndnum = random.randrange (0, lenwords)
    answer = wordlist[rndnum]
    charade = charadelist[rndnum]
    print "***Welcome to Charades!***"
    print "You are given a charade. Try to guess the answer:"
    print '"'+charade+'"'
    guess = raw_input('Your answer: ')
    if guess == answer:
        print "Well done!"
    else:
        print "Sorry, the correct answer is " + '"'+answer+'"' + '.'


reply = ""
while reply != 'no':
    runGame()
    print 'Do you want to play again?'
    reply = raw_input('Type `yes` or `no`: ')
    if reply == 'no':
        print 'Thanks for playing!'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   import random


    #Set up the lists for charades and the  answers (words)
    charadelist = ["Mary's father has 5 daughters: Chacha, Chichi, Cheche, Chocho. What is the name of the 5th daughter?"]             
    wordlist = ["Mary"]

    lencharades = len(charadelist)

    lenwords = len(wordlist)

    rndnum = random.randrange (0, lenwords)

    answer = wordlist[rndnum]

    charade = charadelist[rndnum]

    print "***Welcome to Charades!***"
    print "You are given a charade. Try to guess the answer:"

    rep = "yes"
    while rep == "yes":
      print '"'+charade+'"'
      guess = raw_input('Your answer: ')

      if guess == answer:
          print "Well done!"
      else:
          print "Sorry, the correct answer is " + '"'+answer+'"' + '.'

      print 'Do you want to play again?'
      reply = raw_input('Type `yes` or `no`: ')
      if reply == 'yes':
        pass

      # How do I run the program again??? Please help

      if reply == 'no':
          print 'Thanks for playing!'
          rep = "no"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put your program in a loop.If the input is "no",break out the loop.

```
while(1):
    your code
    if reply == "no":
        break
```